# Do quantum jumps define the color of objects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When an electron jumps to a higher energy level due to the absorption of energy, let's say light, and then later jumps to a lower energy level, is the frequency of the photon that is released, presuming that frequency is of the visible light spectrum, the color that we see?

Comment: I think you can find the answer to this with a simple Google search.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero unfortunately I was unable to find the information with a simple google search, maybe you could enlighten me with a link or an answer? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When an electron jumps to a higher energy level due to the absorption of energy,

Solid state is matter in bulk, it is usually in some [form of a lattice](http://When%20an%20electron%20jumps%20to%20a%20higher%20energy%20level%20due%20to%20the%20absorption%20of%20energy,%20let's%20say%20light,%20and%20then%20once%20it%20jumps%20to%20a%20lower%20energy%20level,%20is%20the%20photon%20that%20is%20released,%20presuming%20its%20frequency%20is%20of%20the%20visible%20light%20spectrum,%20the%20color%20that%20we%20see?), which if opaque, as your question implies , will reflect with elastic scatters the photons that are not absorbed and their energy dissipated in the lattice transitions.

> let's say light, and then once it jumps to a lower energy level, is the photon that is released, presuming its frequency is of the visible light spectrum, the color that we see?

The absorption of photons that interact with the lattice or the surface molecules removes  those frequencies from the light band. The ones that are reflected elastically will give the perceived color. When falling back to lower energies the distribution is in 4pi and will not generally reflect back, as there are many lattice levels to relax into and generate lower frequency photons in all directions.